# Input python using sys

Tags: python

Is it possible to read the character of an input without consuming it?

Example:

```py
while state < 100:
    if read: c = sys.stdin.read(1)
    else: read = True
    if c=='/':
        next_c=sys.stdin.peek(1)
        if next_c=='/':
            state = MT[state][filter('//')]
        else:
            state = MT[state][filter(c)]
    else:
        state = MT[state][filter(c)]
    if state < 100 and state !=0: lexeme += c
```

I want that `next_c` doesn't consume the input character so that in the rest of the runs it is complete.

For example, if I give `a/b` it just prints `a/` because the `b` was read.

Comment: Please provide the code that you're actually trying to run. As shown, this cannot be executed due to TypeError. Also, the value of *state* will never change within the *while* loop

Comment: Try moving, `next_c=sys.stdin.peek(1)` to the `if read` statement. and after `state = MT[state][filter('//')]` write the `sys.stdin.read(1)`

Comment: @pravashpanigrahi Python 3.11.3 does not have a *peek* attribute for *stdin*

Comment: ok, Then `io` module can be used. so now we the `next_c=sys.stdin.peek(1)`, can be changed - `io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, line_buffering=True).peek(1)`. But peek is not available python 3.11. readline() can be used - `sys.stdin.readline()` and also need to change the `next_c` - `c[1] if len(c) > 1 else None` and `c = sys.stdin.read(2)`

Answer (score -1):

In Python, you can use the io.BufferedReader class to wrap the standard input and provide the peek() functionality.

Comment: And how would this look in code? Because if write it as sys.stdin.peek(1) it gives me an error `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'peek'. Did you mean: 'seek'?`

Comment: BufferedReader  not TextIOWrapper